# Why is my machine learning svm code not converging to a predicted value?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, encoding

I have been writing this code and i have gotten to the point where it runs but does not converge unfortunately. Could someone please have a look because I have checked many things and not too sure why it isn't converging. The data set is from here: https://github.com/nshomron/covidpred/blob/master/data/corona_tested_individuals_ver_006.english.csv.zip

The code I have hoped to split it up to make it a bit clear:

```
#---------- IMPORTS ----------

import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
from numpy.core.defchararray import index
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.tools.datetimes import Scalar
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import svm
```

- 

```
#---------- PREPROCESSING ----------
#---------- Import data  ----------

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Saaqib\Documents\Python\PythonProjects\Covidproject\corona_tested_individuals.csv', )

X = data.loc[:, data.columns != 'corona_result']
X = X.loc[:, X.columns != 'test_date']
y = data.iloc[:,6]

#---------- Encode data ----------

Le_X = LabelEncoder()
X['age_60_and_above'] = Le_X.fit_transform(X['age_60_and_above'])
X['gender'] = Le_X.fit_transform(X['gender'])
X['test_indication'] = Le_X.fit_transform(X['test_indication'])
# print('data=',X)
y = Le_X.fit_transform(y)
y = np.array(y)

Hot_enc_X = OneHotEncoder()
enc_X = pd.DataFrame(Hot_enc_X.fit_transform(X[['gender','test_indication']]).toarray())
X = X.join(enc_X)
X = X.drop(columns=['gender','test_indication'])

X = X.replace("None", float('nan'))
X["cough"] = X["cough"].fillna(0)
X["fever"] = X["fever"].fillna(0)
X["sore_throat"] = X["sore_throat"].fillna(0)
X["shortness_of_breath"] = X["shortness_of_breath"].fillna(0)
X["head_ache"] = X["head_ache"].fillna(0)
X["age_60_and_above"] = X["age_60_and_above"].fillna(0)

X['cough'] = X['cough'].astype(float)
X['fever'] = X['fever'].astype(float)
X['sore_throat'] = X['sore_throat'].astype(float)
X['shortness_of_breath'] = X['shortness_of_breath'].astype(float)
X['head_ache'] = X['head_ache'].astype(float)
X['age_60_and_above'] = X['age_60_and_above'].astype(float)
```

- 

```
#---------- Split data set ----------

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

scaler = StandardScaler()

X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)



#---------- Train Model ----------


covid_model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
covid_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = covid_model.predict(X_test)
acc = accuracy_score(y_test,predictions)
print("pred:", predictions)
print("acc:", acc)
```

Comment: How much is your accuracy ?

Comment: Hi, it cant complete running the program so I don't know.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code. `SVM` can be extremely slow on large data. It will take some minutes or maybe hours to train. There are other tools to make SVM faster, but I don't know a lot about them, so I will suggest you to use `RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs = -1)` for quick results.

Comment: @SQB. Always mention what error you are facing exactly. Don't post your thoughts as your errors. I ran all your code on my machine and it ran flawlessly and here I was thinking what could be wrong. Also, as said by @Hobo SVMs are terribly slow especially in `sklearn` based implementation. If you want to use it on large datasets then try to look for the `cuML` i.e. Rapids-based implementation. Btw I ran on a 10% subset dataset.

Comment: @SQB look at [this](https://medium.com/rapids-ai/fast-support-vector-classification-with-rapids-cuml-6e49f4a7d89e) tutorial.

Comment: Thank you everyone! Perhaps I will just need to wait then.

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat by the way, how do I run on a certain percentage of a dataset?

Comment: I used `df = df.sample(frac=0.1, random_state=1234)` to select 10% of the dataset. If you want then it's better to use `train_test_split` along with stratification like this - `train_df, _ = train_test_split(df, train_size=0.1, stratify=df['label'], random_state=1234)`.